# Write a script in crash (debugger) for printing a long list structure

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, crash, crash-dumps

How can we print whole link list in crash utility?

```
crash> struct disk 0xffffffff | grep disk_next
disk_next = 0xf234ff4f4
crash> struct disk 0xf234ff4f4 | grep disk_next
disk_next = 0xf34994
```

I want to print all the addresses of the disk list through some script.

Answer (score 1):

There is "list" command in crash utility which can do these things.